# NPM_ERROR_WHEN_IN _SAILS

Tags: npm, sails.js

node:internal/process/promises:279 triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check bootstrap.js file there is some delay to get the response or return a promise over there in [object, object], resolve that promise and then try or simple implement try catch over there.